django query_utils empty placeholder
I'd like to use django.db.modles.query_utils.Q, the |-operator and defaultdict to create a (set-)union of different conditions, i.e. to filter anything that matches any of them. Therefore it makes sense to start with 'Nothing'.
Does django provide a 'Nothing' (and 'Everything') class, equivalent to Q usagewise, that can be passed to .filter(...), to use as a start and to properly take care of empty edge cases? Similar to how sums have an empty default of 0 and products of 1.
E.g.:
from collections import defaultdict
from django.db.models import Q
from app.models import Foo

# Keep track of which `Foo`'s to fetch for Anne, Bob, Cristian and Dimitrios:
# Hack to match nothing for no conditions (instead of everything).
filters = defaultdict(lambda: Q(pk=-1)) 

# Quirky loops, just as an example of generating filters.
for i, name in enumerate(['Anne', 'Bob', 'Cristian', 'Dimitrios']):
  for age in [25, 10, 5][:i-1]: # empty for Anne
     filters[name] |= Q(age=age)

for name in ['Anne', 'Bob', 'Cristian', 'Dimitrios']:
   # Should return 0 for Anne
   print(name, Foo.objects.filter(filters[name]).count())

Of course, I can simplify this code, for instance by merging the loops, but that's besides the point.
Moreover, a database might support -1 keys and also it seems (slightly) inefficient to check for an entire table for -1. Even if not, this is still ugly and risky.
Weirdly, Q() seems to return everything, so one would guess Q() | Q(pk=-1) would too, but that returns nothing, violating A ⊆ A ∪ B.
